# jQuery plugin inside an independent function

Tags: javascript, jquery, function, plugins, closures

I've been trying to define a function that calls a jquery plugin that works without a selector

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/mouse0270-bootstrap-notify/3.1.7/bootstrap-notify.min.js"></script>
<script>
    $.notify({
        // options
        message: 'Hello World'
    }, {
        // settings
        type: 'danger'
    });
</script>
```

This first one works as intended,
but when trying this next setup

```html
<script>
    function sendNotification() {
        $.notify({
            // options
            message: 'Hello World'
        }, {
            // settings
            type: 'danger'
        });
    }
</script>
```

it throws a **$.notify not defined**

Comment: Make sure that `sendNotification` is initialized and triggered after the notify-script is loaded

Comment: how so ? I call the `sendNotification` function through chrome devtools console. It throws the undefined error

Comment: Is `bootstrap-notify.min.js` still included on your side when calling the function?

Comment: yes it is loaded, I said when using the `$.notify` alone in the console it does work, but when I put it inside the function and run it it throws an error